# How to force all namespace declarations to be attached to the root element?

Tags: python, xml, namespaces, lxml

I am using lxml to generate a xml file.

```
from lxml import etree as ET
```

I register a namespace using this line

```
ET.register_namespace("exp", "http://www.example.com/exp/")
```

If I add an element with

```
root_exp = ET.Element("{http://www.example.com/exp/}root_exp")
```

or an SubElement with

```
foo_hdr = ET.SubElement(root_exp, "{http://www.example.com/exp/}fooHdr")
```

the namespace is defined every time the namespace appears, e.g.

```
<exp:bar xmlns:exp="http://www.example.com/exp/">
   <exp:fooHdr CREATEDATE="2013-03-22T10:28:27.137531">
```

This is well-formed XML afaik, but I think this is not necessary and it looks very verbose. How can this behaviour be suppressed? There should be one definition for each namespace in the root element of the xml file.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE

Minimal example

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
from lxml import etree as ET

ET.register_namespace("exa", "http://www.example.com/test")

root = ET.Element("{http://www.example.com/test}root")

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("example.xml",  encoding="UTF-8", pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True)
```

UPDATE 2

Updated snippet

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
from lxml import etree as ET

ET.register_namespace("exa", "http://www.example.com/test")
ET.register_namespace("axx", "http://www.example.com/foo")

root = ET.Element("{http://www.example.com/test}root")
sub_element = ET.SubElement(root, "{http://www.example.com/test}sub_element")
foo_element = ET.SubElement(sub_element, "{http://www.example.com/foo}foo")
bar_element = ET.SubElement(sub_element, "{http://www.example.com/foo}bar")

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("example.xml",  encoding="UTF-8", pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True)
```

Expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<exa:root xmlns:exa="http://www.example.com/test"/ xmlns:axx="http://www.example.com/foo">
  <exa:sub_element>
    <axx:foo />
    <axx:bar />
  </exa:sub_element>
</exa:root>
```

Is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<exa:root xmlns:exa="http://www.example.com/test">
  <exa:sub_element>
    <axx:foo xmlns:axx="http://www.example.com/foo"/>
    <axx:bar xmlns:axx="http://www.example.com/foo"/>
  </exa:sub_element>
</exa:root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a namespace map:

```
NSMAP = { 'exa': 'http://www.example.com/test',
          'axx': 'http://www.example.com/foo' }

root = ET.Element('{http://www.example.com/test}root', nsmap=NSMAP)
sub_element = ET.SubElement(root, '{http://www.example.com/test}sub_element')
foo_element = ET.SubElement(sub_element, '{http://www.example.com/foo}foo')
bar_element = ET.SubElement(sub_element, '{http://www.example.com/foo}bar')

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)

print(ET.tostring(tree,encoding='UTF-8',pretty_print=True,xml_declaration=True))
```

results in:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<exa:root xmlns:axx="http://www.example.com/foo" xmlns:exa="http://www.examplom/test">
  <exa:sub_element>
    <axx:foo/>
    <axx:bar/>
  </exa:sub_element>
</exa:root>
```

Which is exactly the desired output.

Comment: Thanks! It works! I presumed `register_namespace` does this (in an way).